# Tool for height and width measurement of image in pixel

Tags: html, css

Can anyone suggest me a **tool** to measure the **dimension** of an image in **pixel**.

I need it so that I can use ***a part of the image*** by specifying ***`background-position-x`*** and ***`background-position-y`*** as well as for **height** and **width** after assessing the position of the starting point in the image in terms of pixel.

Comment: I've answered your question recently, and I've seen your questions are downvoted in a row, I would like to suggest you to research for info using google, try it yourself, if you fail, than ask a question, also when users solve your question, and share the code you try, if you can, provide examples, demos, make it interactive so that users will like to share their solutions, also accept their answers by clicking on a green tick if it helps you, this way you pay them back for their efforts

Comment: @Dash: Thanx but Can you suggest me some other light-weight software?

Comment: Use Firefox's "Inspect Element" command right-clicking on the picture. You can see the dimensions on the "Box Model" panel. Also you can set position values on the air and see the results immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Chrome u can get a free add-on called page ruler:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn

Even Inspect element of Google chrome will give you height and width in pixels